# Java Map with two keys - speed comparison of solutions

Tags: java, performance, dictionary

In my program, I'd like to use Map with two keys (Integers). My first idea was to join the integers into a string in some way, eg:

```
String key = k1.toString()+"-"+k2.toString();
```

This solution didn't look good for me: 1) ugly; 2) slow (handling numbers as a text).

I discovered other approaches here on stackoverflow. They were based on encapsulating the integers in one class - one purpose class (MyKey), or more generic one (Pair).

I tried to run some speed tests and my dummy solutions seem to be fastest. After the first shot, I tried to encapsulate the transformation integers-string in a new class (MyString) and run test also against this solution.

The maps definitions were:

```
Map<Pair<Integer,Integer>,String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<MyKey,String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String,String> map3 = new HashMap<>();
Map<MyString,String> map4 = new HashMap<>();
```

The test results were (ran multiple times, seems stable):

```
  map: put+get=total
  1: 52+154=206
  2: 29+77=106
  3: 23+49=72
  3: 17+55=72
```

The solutions with string are faster. Direct concatenating of string keys is faster when searching, slower when inputting.

My questions are:

1) Why are the solutions with String faster? (one call of hashCode()?)

2) Is there any reason why shouldn't be solutions with String used?

---

Additional information:

Number of records in the Map was about 6000.

Test tried to get also values for many unexisting keys. Could it change test results?

In my program, I generate permutations of boolean[N] where M values are true. Once, I get result for certain N,M; I'd like to store them for case I need them again.

And here is complete code of classes used in my example:

```
  class Pair<L,R> {

    private final L left;
    private final R right;

    public Pair(L left, R right) {
      this.left = left;
      this.right = right;
    }

    public L getLeft() { return left; }
    public R getRight() { return right; }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { return left.hashCode() ^ right.hashCode(); }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (o == null) return false;
      if (!(o instanceof Pair)) return false;
      Pair pairo = (Pair) o;
      return this.left.equals(pairo.getLeft()) &&
             this.right.equals(pairo.getRight());
    }
  }

  class MyKey {
      public Integer k1;
      public Integer k2;

      public MyKey(Integer k1, Integer k2) {
          this.k1 = k1;
          this.k2 = k2;
      }

      @Override
      public int hashCode() {
          return k1.hashCode() + 17 * k2.hashCode();
      }

      @Override
      public boolean equals(Object o) {
          if (o == this) {
              return true;
          }
          if (o == null || !(o instanceof MyKey)) {
              return false;
          }
          MyKey cp = MyKey.class.cast(o);
          return k1.equals(cp.k1) && k2.equals(cp.k2);
      }
  }

  class MyString  {
      private String value;

      public MyString(Integer k1, Integer k2) {
          value=k1+"-"+k2;
      }

      @Override
      public int hashCode() {
          return value.hashCode();
      }

      @Override
      public boolean equals(Object o) {
          return o.equals(value);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem you have is the building of Strings, or creating objects just to perform a lookup.

A way around this is to have a Map or Map values. As your keys are primitives you are better off using the trove library. [TObjectIntHashMap](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TObjectIntHashMap.html) and [TIntIntHashMap](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TIntIntHashMap.html)

e.g.

```
TObjectIntHashMap<TIntIntHashMap> map = ...
int val = map.get(k1).get(k2);
```

Using this approach no objects are required to create keys or values.

If you want to pair the keys you can use the follow

```
TLongIntHashMap map = ...
int val = map.get(((long) k1 << 32) | k2);
```

e.g.

```
long key = ((long) k1 << 32) | k2;
map.adjustOrPut(key, 1, 1); // a counter for this key.
```

Comment: As I see in the second code sample, I just need to set some limit for the key number (it can be even less than range of int), ~concatenate numbers bitwise and use it as a one number. Is that right?
First code sample: I wasn't sure if creating map of maps is a good way.

Comment: You are right, but you don't gain much either way.  I would do what you believe is conceptually clearer for your problem.

Answer (score 5):

This should be the most performant double-integer key:

```
class MyKey {
  public final int k1, k2;
  MyKey(int k1, int k2) { this.k1 = k1; this.k2 = k2; }
  public int hashCode() { return k1 ^ k2; }
  public boolean equals(Object o) { 
    MyKey that;
    return o instanceof MyKey && (that = (MyKey)o).k1 == k1 && that.k2 == k2;
  }
```

As for your test results, you should be very careful with microbenchmarking. Are you sure you did all the incantations like warming up, GC-ing, carefully writing code that the JIT cannot compile out of existence, etc? If not, I warmly recommend Google Caliper instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: +1. Depending on the k1/k2 pairs used for the key, you might want to alter `hashCode()` to avoid having the same results for (a,b) and (b,a).

Comment: @Axel My implementation was taken from `Long.hashCode`, but it would of course be ideal to fit it optimally to OP's situation.

Comment: Test results: No, I am not sure. I realized the test are not 100% punctual, but difference 2-3 times seemed different enough for me, even using not the best approaches.
Anyway, I had a brief look over Google Caliper and it seems cool, I'll have a deeper look. Thanks!

Comment: The difference between interpreted and compiled code is much more than 2-3 times, so caution is always necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> 2) Is there any reason why shouldn't be solutions with String used?

If you ask about the given approach:

```
String key = k1.toString()+"-"+k2.toString();
```

The problem is:

```
k1 = "a-b"
k2 = "c"
```

and

```
k1 = "a"
k2 = "b-c"
```

(and similar)

have the same keys.

If you ask about using a class:

To have a class dealing with this is more clean. Because then your class cares about the implementation, not the caller.
This means, you do not have to think about if using a "-" or "." or "#" or whatever is correct now, and if you want to change it, you change it inside the class. Not at different locations scattered around the sourcecode.

The right approach for the hashcode implementation depends on your data. Eclipse suggests for a general way:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((k1 == null) ? 0 : k1.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((k2 == null) ? 0 : k2.hashCode());
    return result;
}
```

which looks ok for me.

Question 1 is a bit more complex. It depends heavily on the input data.

A general advice: Do not care about performance, as long as you do not have to take care about it. This means, only if the solution is too slow, start to profile it and improve the most significant parts. Other then that, readability and maintainability is always the first goal.